# ZFS: i/o error - all block copies unavailable on reboot

Tags: freebsd, zfs, zpool

I am trying to create RAID-Z pool on 3 disks, but I'm getting this error after reboot:

```
zpool create -f -o altroot=/mnt datapool raidz vtbd0p3 /dev/da0 /dev/da1
```

Error is

```
ZFS: i/o error - all block copies unavailable
invalid format

FreeBSD/x86 boot
ZFS: i/o error - all block copies unavailable
can't fild dataset /boot/kernel/kernel
Default: datapool/boot:/boot/kernel/kernel
boot:
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you trashed you FreeBSD installation, creating a new zpool on `/dev/da0` and `/dev/da1` (overwriting what was previously there).

I strongly suggest you to *never* create a pool with `-f` unless you *really* know what you are doing.

Comment: i tried without -f but still same issue persisting ```root@mfsbsd:~ # zpool create -o altroot=/mnt datapool vtbd0p3 /dev/da 
da0% da1% ;
zpool create -o altroot=/mnt datapool raidz vtbd0p3 /dev/da0 /dev/da1 ;
 zfs create -o mountpoint=/ -o canmount=noauto datapool/boot ;
mount -t zfs datapool/boot /mnt ;
cp -r /temp/* /mnt/. ;
 zpool set bootfs=datapool/boot datapool ;
 zfs create -o mountpoint=/storage -o canmount=noauto datapool/storage ;
 zfs create -o mountpoint=/conf -o canmount=noauto datapool/conf ;
```

Comment: Using `zpool create -f` you overwrote your original boot pool. So you can't "recover" re-creating another pool (overwriting it yet another time). You probably need to reinstall your FreeBSD system.

Comment: no, im not over writing. i created the new droplet and created partitions and zpool without -f as per above commands. please help me

Comment: @SreekanthChityala using ZFS requires some understanding of the underlying storage stack, so I strongly advise you to read its documentation before using it.

Comment: now i created partitions(rooot,swap,boot) on each hard disk. now able to create raidz with 3 hard disks on each vdev for upto 2 vdevs. but getting same zfs i/o error if i create 2 vdevs contains 4 disks per vdev. or more disks per vdev